# The spacing between the latex tables is different

Tags: tables, spacing, columns

Now i am drawing the table using latex code. 
However, the spacing between the lines of the table does not seem appropriate (slightly off)

Here is the table what i made
[image]

However, i want this type of form (to clarify, using powerpoint :/ , for 2 columns width)

[image]

Additianally, similar type of the table below, is also needed (for 1 column width)

[image]

I almost spent three days... 
And here is the 'messy' code !!!

```
\begin{table*}[]\label{table_test}\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{4 mm}
\caption{ }
\begin{tabular}{clccccccccccl}
\hline
\multicolumn{13}{c}{(1) MachineLearning-based}           
\\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Method}    
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Method}
& A01 & A02 & A03 & A04 & A05 & A06 & A07 & A08 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{A09} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Mean}                                                                                    \\ \hline 
~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Model3}                                  
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}00.00\\ $\pm$00.00\end{tabular}}        
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}00.00\\ $\pm$00.00\end{tabular}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}00.00\\ $\pm$00.00\end{tabular}}      
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}00.00\\ $\pm$00.00\end{tabular}}     
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}00.00\\ $\pm$00.00\end{tabular}}
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}00.00\\ $\pm$00.00\end{tabular}}      
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}00.00\\ $\pm$00.00\end{tabular}}     
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}00.00\\ $\pm$00.00\end{tabular}}    
& \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}00.00\\ $\pm$00.00\end{tabular}}
& \multicolumn{2}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}00.00\\ $\pm$00.00\end{tabular}}                                  \\

\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\textbf{Model4}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{00.00}\\ \textbf{$\pm$00.00}\end{tabular}}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{00.00}\\ \textbf{$\pm$00.00}\end{tabular}}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{00.00}\\ \textbf{$\pm$00.00}\end{tabular}}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{00.00}\\ \textbf{$\pm$00.00}\end{tabular}}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{00.00}\\ \textbf{$\pm$00.00}\end{tabular}}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{00.00}\\ \textbf{$\pm$00.00}\end{tabular}}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{00.00}\\ \textbf{$\pm$00.00}\end{tabular}}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{00.00}\\ \textbf{$\pm$00.00}\end{tabular}}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{00.00}\\ \textbf{$\pm$00.00}\end{tabular}}} 
& \multicolumn{2}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{00.00}\\ \textbf{$\pm$00.00$^{**}$}\end{tabular}}} 
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{clccccccccccl}
\hline
\multicolumn{13}{c}{(2) DeepLearning-based} 

~~~~~~~~~~~
SAME as above
~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a minimum working example (MWE) of your table in code block so that we can specify what you can do.

Comment: Hello, @TeddyvanJerry !!! I appociate your comment! I uploaded my latex code!!! Thank you for spending time on my problem.

Comment: When you write "PowerPoint", do you actually mean the `beamer` document class? Please advise.

Comment: Actually, I couldn't express exactly what I wanted with latex, so I drew the table using the power point function. But I first learned about beamer this time. Thank you so much for letting me know :D

Comment: I suspect the conversion program, in particular putting tabular inside \multicolumn.  Each tabular adds a little space above and below.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I appreciate for your comment, thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following solution tries to simplify the "look" of the table, mainly by getting rid of the vertical rules and using fewer horizontal rules. I would also abstain from using `\rowcolor` and `\cellcolor` as colorizing cells and entire rows doesn't appear to do anything other than provide gaudiness and cheap entertainment -- at least for the table at hand.

The code shown below employs a shortcut macro -- named, not very imaginatively, `\myarray` -- to allow replacing the rather complicated-looking

```
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{00.00}\\ \textbf{$\pm$00.00}\end{tabular}}}
```

with a much more manageable

```
\myarray[\boldmath]{00.00 \\ \pm 00.00}
```

If you don't need to **bold-face** the main argument of `\myarray`, just omit the macro's optional argument, i.e, `[\boldmath]`.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%% Define a handy shortcut macro:
\newcommand\myarray[2][]{\ensuremath{#1\begin{array}[t]{r} #2 \end{array}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{A table with two subpanels}

\tiny
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\centerline{%
\begin{tabular*}{1.1\textwidth}{ l @{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{10}{c} }

\toprule
Method  
& A01 & A02 & A03 & A04 & A05 & A06 & A07 & A08 & A09 & Mean \\ 
\midrule
\addlinespace[2mm]
\multicolumn{4}{l}{(1) Machine Learning-based} \\ 
\addlinespace
Model2                                 
& \myarray{01.00 \\ \pm 00.00}        
& \myarray{02.00 \\ \pm 00.00} 
& \myarray{03.00 \\ \pm 00.00}      
& \myarray{04.00 \\ \pm 00.00}     
& \myarray{05.00 \\ \pm 00.00}
& \myarray{06.00 \\ \pm 00.00}  
& \myarray{07.00 \\ \pm 00.00}     
& \myarray{08.00 \\ \pm 00.00}    
& \myarray{08.00 \\ \pm 00.00}
& \myarray{05.00 \\ \pm 00.00} 
\\
\addlinespace
Model3                                 
& \myarray{21.00 \\ \pm 00.00}        
& \myarray{22.00 \\ \pm 00.00} 
& \myarray{23.00 \\ \pm 00.00}      
& \myarray{24.00 \\ \pm 00.00}     
& \myarray{25.00 \\ \pm 00.00}
& \myarray{26.00 \\ \pm 00.00}  
& \myarray{27.00 \\ \pm 00.00}     
& \myarray{28.00 \\ \pm 00.00}    
& \myarray{29.00 \\ \pm 00.00}
& \myarray{25.00 \\ \pm 00.00} 
\\
\addlinespace[4mm]
\multicolumn{4}{l}{(2) Deep Learning-based} \\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Model4} 
& \myarray[\boldmath]{01.00 \\ \pm 00.00} 
& \myarray[\boldmath]{02.00 \\ \pm 00.00} 
& \myarray[\boldmath]{03.00 \\ \pm 00.00}
& \myarray[\boldmath]{04.00 \\ \pm 00.00} 
& \myarray[\boldmath]{05.00 \\ \pm 00.00} 
& \myarray[\boldmath]{06.00 \\ \pm 00.00} 
& \myarray[\boldmath]{07.00 \\ \pm 00.00} 
& \myarray[\boldmath]{08.00 \\ \pm 00.00} 
& \myarray[\boldmath]{09.00 \\ \pm 00.00} 
& \myarray[\boldmath]{05.00 \\ \pm 00.00\rlap{${}^{**}$}}\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Model5} 
& \myarray[\boldmath]{41.00 \\ \pm 00.00} 
& \myarray[\boldmath]{42.00 \\ \pm 00.00} 
& \myarray[\boldmath]{43.00 \\ \pm 00.00}
& \myarray[\boldmath]{44.00 \\ \pm 00.00} 
& \myarray[\boldmath]{45.00 \\ \pm 00.00} 
& \myarray[\boldmath]{46.00 \\ \pm 00.00} 
& \myarray[\boldmath]{47.00 \\ \pm 00.00} 
& \myarray[\boldmath]{48.00 \\ \pm 00.00} 
& \myarray[\boldmath]{49.00 \\ \pm 00.00} 
& \myarray[\boldmath]{45.00 \\ \pm 00.00}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your answer was very helpful. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

An experiment how to write your table with use of the `tabularray` package with its libraries `booktabs` and `siunitx` (which load packages of the same names) and package `changepage` by which is extend `\textwidth` of table:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{A table with two subpanels}

\begin{adjustwidth}{-1.5em}{-1.5em}
\tiny
\sisetup{minimum-integer-digits=2,
         detect-weight,
         mode=text}
\SetTblrStyle{remark}{fg=black!80}
\begin{talltblr}[
       entry = none,
       label = none,
remark{Note} = {\sisetup{minimum-integer-digits=1}  % <---
                Symbols *, **, and *** denote significance at the
                \qty{10}{\%}, \qty{5}{\%} and \qty{1}{\%} levels, respectively.}
                ]{colsep = 0pt,
                 colspec = {    l 
                           *{9}{X[c, si]}
                                X[c, si={table-format=-2.2{**}}]
                           },
                 row{1}  = {guard},
                 row{3-Z}={rowsep=0pt},
                 row{odd[3-7]}  = {abovesep=1ex},
                 row{even[8-Z]} = {abovesep=1ex},
                 row{8-Z}={font=\bfseries},
                 }
    \toprule
Method
    & A01 & A02 & A03 & A04 & A05 & A06 & A07 & A08 & A09 & Mean \\
    \midrule
\SetCell[c=4]{l, guard}    (1) Machine Learning-based
    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &           \\
Model 2
    & 01.00 & 02.00 & 03.00 & 04.00 & 05.00 & 06.00 & 07.00 & 08.00 & 09.00 & 10.00     \\
    & \pm 00.00     & \pm 00.00     & \pm 00.00     & \pm 00.00     & \pm 00.00 
    & \pm 00.00     & \pm 00.00     & \pm 00.00     & \pm 00.00     & \pm 00.00         \\
Model 3
    & 01.00 & 02.00 & 03.00 & 04.00 & 05.00 & 06.00 & 07.00 & 08.00 & 09.00 & 10.00     \\
    & \pm 00.00     & \pm 00.00     & \pm 00.00     & \pm 00.00     & \pm 00.00
    & \pm 00.00     & \pm 00.00     & \pm 00.00     & \pm 00.00     & \pm 00.00         \\

\SetCell[c=4]{l, guard}    (2) Deep Learning-based
    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &           \\
Model 4
    & 01.00 & 02.00 & 03.00 & 04.00 & 05.00 & 06.00 & 07.00 & 08.00 & 09.00 & 10.00     \\
    & \pm 00.00     & \pm 00.00     & \pm 00.00     & \pm 00.00     & \pm 00.00
    & \pm 00.00     & \pm 00.00     & \pm 00.00     & \pm 00.00     & \pm 00.00\TblrNote{**}   \\
Model 5
    & 01.00 & 02.00 & 03.00 & 04.00 & 05.00 & 06.00 & 07.00 & 08.00 & 09.00 & 10.00     \\
    & \pm 00.00     & \pm 00.00     & \pm 00.00     & \pm 00.00     & \pm 00.00
    & \pm 00.00     & \pm 00.00     & \pm 00.00     & \pm 00.00     & \pm 00.00         \\
    \bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't adopt it. But it was very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @20am847, what you mean with "adopt it"? Since proposed solution is a bit experimental (for me). I'm curious, what problems you have with code.

Comment: Oh i just want to say i couldn't 'accept' your answer becuase i already accept the other one. Apologize to confuse you. Also, your advice works well!!! No problem!